# how to compress a List in f#?

Tags: list, functional-programming, f#

Hi I'm new to f# and I got this exercise I can't figure out: 
"Implement a Function :"
 `let compress (l : List<'a>) : List<'a> = ...`
That removes consecutive occurences of the same element in l. for example compressing [a;a;a;a;b;b;c] to [a;b;c]

I'm not allowed to use the built-in functions of f# and need to do this with pattern matching.

My current code (it's not much) :

```
let rec compress (l: List<'a>) : List<'a> = 
    match l with
    | [] -> l
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: Considering it's an exercise, maybe I'll just give a hint? Just like your other question, create an inner rec function that has an extra param `last`. Compare that to the current head of the list, if equal, don't prepend.

Comment: Another hint: when writing recursive functions for lists, start out with the inner rec function doing nothing but building the same list again. This will inverse the list, so add `List.rev` at the end. Then add the business logic. Hope this gets you in the right direction.

Comment: I'd not worry too much about writing an inner function, I'd concentrate on the cases....an empty list -> an empty list...correct....a list with 1 element -> a list with 1 element...a list with 2 or more elements...well consider what happens if the 1st two elements are the same, and then consider what happens if they are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any recursive function you need to consider: 1. the terminal case and 2. the general case.  In your scenario:

1. the empty list *[]*
2. non-empty list *x::xs*  (where x represents the head of the list and xs the rest aka tail)

The other important aspect to consider when you build such a functions is to assume it works for a previous value.  For example in the case of factorial, we assume the function already works for a previous scenario e.g. factorial of n-1.

```
let fact n = 
   match n with
   | 0 | 1 -> 1
   | _ -> n * fact (n-1)
```